# Paypal URL post issue

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web, paypal

I am trying to use Paypal on my web-application,
This the code of the Paypal form :

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXX"><input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/he_IL/IL/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - הדרך הקלה והבטוחה יותר לשלם באינטרנט!"><img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/he_IL/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
<input type="hidden" name="full_name" value="Full name62249"><input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="custom" value="110"><input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com"><input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.adv.nmc-medical.co.il/paypal-thanks">
</form>
```

It works correctly in the desktop browsers. but in mobile it returns an empty array from the POST.
I have printed the POST Array that returned from Paypal:
in desktop

```
array ( 'txn_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'mc_currency' => 'ILS', 'mc_fee' => '4.60', 'mc_gross' => '100.00', 'protection_eligibility' => 'ELIGIBLE', 'payment_date' => '2016-12-20T09:06:06Z', 'payment_fee' => '4.60', 'payment_gross' => '100.00', 'payment_status' => 'Completed', 'payment_type' => 'INSTANT_TRANSFER', 'business' => 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'receiver_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'payer_email' => 'XXXXXXXXX', 'payer_id' => 'XXXXXXXX', 'payer_status' => 'VERIFIED', 'first_name' => 'XXXXXX', 'last_name' => 'XXXXX', 'address_name' => 'loai Shi', 'address_street' => 'יXXXXXXXXX 5 XXXXXXX 4', 'address_city' => 'XXXXX', 'address_country_code' => 'IL', 'address_zip' => 'XXXXX', 'residence_country' => 'IL', 'item_name' => 'nmc test', 'quantity' => '1', 'custom' => '99', 'charset' => 'windows-1255', )
```

in mobile :

```
array()
```

I have i done wrong?

Comment: use cmd value as `_mobile-express-checkout`  for mobile